# If two fractions add up to 1, are their denominators the same?

Tags: fractions

If two fraction add up to 1, what is the relation between their denominators? Are their denominators equal?

If $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=1$, then, is what is the relation between $b$ and $d$?

I was working on a problem. To solve the problem i need to know the relation between the denominators of fractions which add up to 1. I have tried to find out a relation by using the given equation but i could not obtain any useful result. I have searched the internet but could not find any help.

Comment: $\frac 13 + \frac 46=1$. $\frac 13 + \frac{-2}{-3} = 1$.

Comment: The "denominator" of a fraction is not well-defined, unless one assumes it's in lowest terms and positive denominator, or something else to make there always be a unique denominator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$1-\frac ab=\frac{b-a}b $$